# Enable ScreenCast from ADB - TV

Tags: adb, android-tv, screencast

I would need to be able to remotely control and monitor a TV running Android 9.0. In order to do so, I have been using WebKey without major issues...
One problem is happening with one TV model is that it says that screencast is not enabled and therefore, WebKey is not able to get video from the screen.

**Is it possible to enable this option from ADB (eg. modifying some configuration file)?**

I have been looking around the filesystem and trying with "getprop", "settings" but could not find a possible solution or workaround. I have also tried using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) and it works fine using ADB over Ethernet in the same LAN (both video and control works ok).

Comment: scrcpy copies it's own binary onto the Android device and runs it for generating the video stream. Also a program started via adb has permissions apps don't have. ScreenCast my be disabled/not present to avoid conflicts with recording of DRM protected material.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, is there a way to enable ScreenCast from "outside" the TV?

Comment: try to sideload 3rd party apk http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JHMPP9S